# CMake toolset specification seems to be ignored

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile instant-ngp, but there are bugs building on Windows that require you to force MSVC to 14.25 ([Documented in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/3485#issuecomment-854995048).)

I'm trying to override this with `-T version=14.25` or `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=version=14.25`, but they just don't work.

```
> cmake . -B build -T 'version=14.25'
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30146.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30146.0
...
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
...
```

And it definitely builds with the 14.29 compiler.
14.25 is installed, and I know CMake can see it because if I try a version like 14.24 I get an error message about *that* not being installed, but 14.25 works.

How do I make CMake respect this setting instead of instantly ignoring it?

Comment: Have you run the configuration for the same build dir before? CMake refuses to update the compiler after the initial configuration which would require you to delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build dir or pass the `--fresh` option during configuration (that's a very recent addition to cmake though and may not be available in your version)... Furthermore is the desired version available in the VS Gui for selection via project properties?

Comment: I have repeatedly deleted the build directory in between attempts, so I don't think that's the issue.

Unfortunately I don't know where the project properties are in VS—I only use the VS installer for installing compilers so I can use them from the command line. I will try to check later.

Answer (score 0):

I found some info for this problem here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22420

It turns out that running vcvarsall.bat or starting your build from a "Developer Command Prompt" will set various environment variables that forcibly set the toolset version in a way that CMake can't override.

So the answer is to run your cmake commands from a plain command prompt and not from a "Developer Command Prompt".